# Check if Layer is a DEM programatically

Tags: pyqgis, dem

I loaded several layers, some of them are DEMs of different data type: ASCII and TIFF. I want to check every layer if it is a DEM or not. I found the function [hasElevation](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayerElevationProperties.html#ae629598490ee0ebe43ced06160f7bd3b), which should return true if the layer has a Z component.

When I test all loaded layers with the following code I receive not the true and false results I expected:

```
layers = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().children()
for i in layers:
    print(i.layer().elevationProperties().hasElevation())
```

For ASCII and TIFF files with Z values I receive false where I expected true.
Did I do something wrong?
Is there a different way to check my layers if they are a DEM layer?

Comment: How do you decide if something is a DEM as a human? Do you consider any TIFF a DEM?

Comment: I think the hasElevation method is for layers where you set up an elevation setting in its properties.

Comment: DEM is a raster layer, hasElevation is for vector layers. If the raster layer has single band (see bandCount() method of raster layer) which is a float value (see dataType() method of raster layer, the result is coded 6 = float32, 7 = float64). You can never be sure if this value is elevation or temperature or some other value. :(

Comment: @Zoltan - hasElevation is implmented by  Mesh, PointCloud, Raster and Vector layers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will return `True` if you go into the layer properties and tick Elevation -> Represents Elevation Surface.

A raster doesn't implicitly store elevation, it's values can represent anything really.  So you have to tell QGIS if it's an elevation surface.

[image]

[image]

On the other hand, vector  (if created with Z dimension) and point cloud data implicitly contain a Z dimension and you don't have to specify that it is an Elevation Surface.

[image]

[image]

[image]